# dataset created with d3.nest isn't drawing correctly

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to visualize a dataset to see major players in the pangolin trade. I want each country to be part of a categorical scale on the y-axis, and the x-axis is the date, and I want each trade instance to be represented as a circle, with x being the date it happened, y being the position for that particular country, and r being the number of instances accumulated so far (represented in my data as r). Basically my data is from 2010 to 2016, and includes the country name where pangolins are either imported to or exported from, the count (accumulated trade instances up until this date), and the date (yyyy-mm-dd).
Below is part of my data, which I store in the variable trade:

```
[{"date":"2010-10-22","country":"Thailand","rank":4,"count":1},{"date":"2010-10-28","country":"Malaysia","rank":2,"count":1},{"date":"2010-11-8","country":"Thailand","rank":4,"count":2},{"date":"2010-11-18","country":"Nepal","rank":7,"count":1},{"date":"2010-11-22","country":"China","rank":5,"count":1},{"date":"2010-11-22","country":"China","rank":5,"count":2},{"date":"2010-11-27","country":"India","rank":1,"count":1},{"date":"2010-11-28","country":"India","rank":1,"count":2},{"date":"2010-11-28","country":"India","rank":1,"count":3},{"date":"2010-11-30","country":"India","rank":1,"count":4},{"date":"2010-12-17","country":"Malaysia","rank":2,"count":2},{"date":"2010-12-22","country":"Vietnam","rank":3,"count":1},{"date":"2011-01-3","country":"Nepal","rank":7,"count":2},{"date":"2011-02-12","country":"Myanmar","rank":8,"count":1},{"date":"2011-02-25","country":"Malaysia","rank":2,"count":3},{"date":"2011-02-26","country":"Malaysia","rank":2,"count":4},{"date":"2011-03-2","country":"South Africa","rank":18,"count":1},{"date":"2011-03-2","country":"Rwanda","rank":35,"count":1},{"date":"2011-03-2","country":"Mozambique","rank":22,"count":1},{"date":"2011-03-2","country":"Kenya","rank":12,"count":1},{"date":"2011-03-3","country":"China","rank":5,"count":3},{"date":"2011-02-21","country":"Vietnam","rank":3,"count":2},{"date":"2011-03-24","country":"Malaysia","rank":2,"count":5},{"date":"2011-04-4","country":"Malaysia","rank":2,"count":6},{"date":"2011-03-25","country":"India","rank":1,"count":5},{"date":"2011-03-26","country":"Malaysia","rank":2,"count":7},{"date":"2011-04-2","country":"Nepal","rank":7,"count":3},{"date":"2011-04-20","country":"Thailand","rank":4,"count":3},{"date":"2011-05-11","country":"China","rank":5,"count":4},{"date":"2011-05-11","country":"China","rank":5,"count":5},{"date":"2011-05-26","country":"Indonesia","rank":6,"count":1},{"date":"2011-05-26","country":"India","rank":1,"count":6},{"date":"2011-05-29","country":"Indonesia","rank":6,"count":2},{"date":"2011-06-6","country":"India","rank":1,"count":7},{"date":"2011-06-7","country":"Mozambique","rank":22,"count":2},{"date":"2011-06-5","country":"India","rank":1,"count":8},{"date":"2011-06-12","country":"Malaysia","rank":2,"count":8},{"date":"2011-06-13","country":"Singapore","rank":21,"count":1},{"date":"2011-06-14","country":"Malaysia","rank":2,"count":9},{"date":"2011-06-17","country":"India","rank":1,"count":9},{"date":"2011-06-19","country":"India","rank":1,"count":10},{"date":"2011-06-26","country":"Thailand","rank":4,"count":4},{"date":"2011-06-30","country":"India","rank":1,"count":11},{"date":"2011-07-4","country":"Malaysia","rank":2,"count":10},{"date":"2011-07-5","country":"Zimbabwe","rank":14,"count":1},{"date":"2011-07-12","country":"Indonesia","rank":6,"count":3},{"date":"2011-07-18","country":"Indonesia","rank":6,"count":4},{"date":"2011-07-27","country":"Nepal","rank":7,"count":4},{"date":"2011-08-16","country":"Nepal","rank":7,"count":5},{"date":"2011-08-19","country":"Namibia","rank":33,"count":1},{"date":"2011-08-23","country":"India","rank":1,"count":12},{"date":"2010-09-17","country":"Myanmar","rank":8,"count":2},{"date":"2011-09-1","country":"Zimbabwe","rank":14,"count":2},{"date":"2011-09-13","country":"Indonesia","rank":6,"count":5},{"date":"2011-09-13","country":"Malaysia","rank":2,"count":11},{"date":"2011-09-13","country":"Myanmar","rank":8,"count":3},{"date":"2011-09-21","country":"Malaysia","rank":2,"count":12},{"date":"2011-09-26","country":"Thailand","rank":4,"count":5},{"date":"2011-09-30","country":"Indonesia","rank":6,"count":6},{"date":"2011-10-1","country":"Sri Lanka","rank":19,"count":1},{"date":"2011-10-6","country":"India","rank":1,"count":13},{"date":"2011-10-7","country":"India","rank":1,"count":14},{"date":"2011-10-18","country":"Indonesia","rank":6,"count":7},{"date":"2011-10-18","country":"Indonesia","rank":6,"count":8},{"date":"2011-10-18","country":"Indonesia","rank":6,"count":9},{"date":"2011-10-22","country":"India","rank":1,"count":15},{"date":"2011-10-24","country":"India","rank":1,"count":16},{"date":"2011-11-28","country":"United States","rank":32,"count":1},{"date":"2011-12-15","country":"Vietnam","rank":3,"count":3},{"date":"2011-12-27","country":"Thailand","rank":4,"count":6},{"date":"2012-01-4","country":"Philippines","rank":15,"count":1},{"date":"2012-01-5","country":"Kenya","rank":12,"count":2},{"date":"2012-01-6","country":"Philippines","rank":15,"count":2},{"date":"2012-01-17","country":"Philippines","rank":15,"count":3},{"date":"2012-01-24","country":"China","rank":5,"count":6},{"date":"2012-02-22","country":"Malaysia","rank":2,"count":13},{"date":"2012-03-1","country":"Malaysia","rank":2,"count":14},{"date":"2012-03-19","country":"Pakistan","rank":11,"count":1},{"date":"2012-03-21","country":"Malaysia","rank":2,"count":15},{"date":"2012-03-23","country":"Vietnam","rank":3,"count":4},{"date":"2012-04-27","country":"Vietnam","rank":3,"count":5},{"date":"2012-04-23","country":"Belgium","rank":31,"count":1},{"date":"2012-06-7","country":"Thailand","rank":4,"count":7},{"date":"2012-06-7","country":"Thailand","rank":4,"count":8}];
```

and here is my code:

```
    var margin = {left:120, top:20, right:0, bottom:50};
    var width = 1000;
    var height = 800;


    var data=trade;


    var tradeByCountry = d3.nest()
      .key(function(d) { return d.country; })
      .entries(trade);

      console.log(tradeByCountry);

      tradeByCountry.forEach(function(country){
        country['number']=country.values.length;
        console.log(country);
      });


      var country_colors = ["#393b79","#5254a3", '#6b6ecf', '#9c9ede', '#637939', '#8ca252','#b5cf6b','#cedb9c',
        '#8c6d31','#bd9e39','#e7ba52','#e7cb94','#843c39','#ad494a','#d6616b','#e7969c','#7b4173','#a55194',
        '#ce6dbd','#de9ed6', '#9467bd', '#c5b0d5','#3182bd', '#6baed6','#17becf','#9edae5','#e6550d','#fd8d3c','#fdae6b',
        '#31a354','#74c476','#a1d99b','#d62728','#ff9896','#7f7f7f','#c7c7c7'];


       var colors = d3.scale.ordinal()
                    .domain(d3.range(tradeByCountry.length))
                    .range(country_colors);




      tradeByCountry.sort(function(x, y){
           return d3.descending(x.number, y.number);
        })


      var countriesArray = [];


      tradeByCountry.forEach(function(country){
            countriesArray.push(country.key);

      });

      console.log(countriesArray);


      var x = d3.time.scale()
        .rangeRound([0, width]);

        var y = d3.scale.linear()
            .range([height, 0]);


        var timeFormat = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d");

        x.domain([timeFormat.parse('2010-10-22'),timeFormat.parse('2016-12-30')]);
        y.domain(countriesArray);


        var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(x)
            .orient("bottom");

        var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(y)
            .orient("left");

        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                .append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

            svg.append("g")
              .attr("class", "x axis")
              .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
              .call(xAxis)
            .append("text")
              .attr("class", "label")
              .attr("x", width)
              .attr("y", -6)
              .style("text-anchor", "end")
              .text("date");

          svg.append("g")
              .attr("class", "y axis")
              .call(yAxis)
            .append("text")
              .attr("class", "label")
              .attr("transform", "translate(35,-25)")
              .attr("y", 6)
              .attr("dy", ".71em")
              .style("text-anchor", "end")
              .text("countries");



            svg.selectAll(".dot")
            .data(tradeByCountry)
            .enter().append("circle")
              .attr("class", "dot")
              .attr("r", 7)
              .attr("cx", function(d) { return 0; })
              .attr("cy", function(d,i) { return (height/tradeByCountry.length)*i; })
              .style("fill", function(d,i) { return colors(i); });


            svg.selectAll("text.labels")
                .data(tradeByCountry)
                .enter()
                .append("text")
                .text(function(d) {return d.key})
                .attr("x", 0)
              .attr("y", function(d,i) { return (height/tradeByCountry.length)*i; })
              .attr("transform", "translate(-120,5)")
              .attr("fill",function(d,i) { return colors(i); });


              svg.selectAll('.line')
                .data(tradeByCountry)
                .enter().append('line')
                .attr("x1", 0)     // x position of the first end of the line
                .attr("y1",function(d,i) { return (height/tradeByCountry.length)*i; })
                .attr("x2", width)     // x position of the second end of the line
                .attr("y2", function(d,i) { return (height/tradeByCountry.length)*i; }) 
                .style("stroke",function(d,i) { return colors(i); })
                .attr("id", function(d){return d.key});



          //PROBLEM HERE!!!!!!!!!!!
                var g = svg
                .selectAll("g")
                .data(tradeByCountry)
                .enter().append("g")        
                .selectAll(".dot")
                .data(function(d) {return d.values;})
                .enter().append("circle")
                .attr("id", function(d){ return d.count;})
                .attr("r", function(d){return d.count;})
                .attr("cx", function(d,i) { console.log (d.date);return (x(timeFormat.parse(d.date))); })
                .attr("cy", function(d,i) { return (height/tradeByCountry.length)*i; })
                .style("fill", function(d,i) { return colors(i); });
```

I am having trouble specifically at the very last part of my code, where I can't get all the circles to draw and not in the correct r, as I would like r to increase as the trade accumulates over time for a country, instead it seems that r is different according to country:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things, firstly in your example `.selectAll("g")` at the point you mark as having the error was picking up g elements in the axes, so the first few countries weren't getting their data displayed. This doesn't appear to be the case in your screenshot but it was happening given the code you posted, so I just qualified those `g`s with the `.country` class.

The second thing, and what was causing your specific problem was this line:

```
.attr("cy", function(d,i) { return (height/tradeByCountry.length)*i; })
```

I'm guessing you thought the index variable `i` here was still tied to the tradeByCountry array, which it would have been after `selectAll("g.country").data(tradebyCountry)` but at this point we've now made a nested selection `.selectAll(".dot")` on `d.values` for each country's data so `i` is now indexing those list of values. So that line of code above will take the values for each country and separate them all vertically, always starting from the top row - when in fact you want them on the same line, just separated by country.

```
What you wanted (I = India, M = Malaysia, T = Thailand)
I---    I0      I1       I2
M---       M0M1                       M2
T---           T0    T1        T2

What you were getting
I---    I0 M0 T0
M---        M1  I1   T1
T---                     I2    T2     M2
```

This was also hidden by the fact .attr("fill") also had the same mistake so the colours on each row were consistent (I've used `d.rank` instead to fix it).

Solution 1: To make sure the values stay on the same correct line use `i` before you do the nested selection so it still refers to the countries like this, which will offset each `g` element by the correct amount:

```
  .attr("transform", function(d,i) {
        return "translate(0,"+(height/tradeByCountry.length)*i+")";
   })
```

and simply set `cy` to be zero for everything you add to this `g` element and they'll all be in a straight line (and on the right line)

Full code at the PROBLEM HERE! stage:

```
var g = svg
                    .selectAll("g.country")
                    .data(tradeByCountry)
                    .enter().append("g")
                    .attr("class", "country")
                    .attr("transform", function(d,i) {
                        return "translate(0,"+(height/tradeByCountry.length)*i+")";
                      })
                    .selectAll(".dot")
                    .data(function(d) {return d.values;})
                    .enter().append("circle")
                    .attr("class", "dot")
                    .attr("id", function(d){ return d.country+"_"+d.date+"_"+d.count;})
                    .attr("r", function(d){ return d.count;})
                    .attr("cx", function(d,i) { console.log (d.date);return (x(timeFormat.parse(d.date))); })
                    .attr("cy", function(d,i) { return 0; })
                    .style("fill", function(d,i) { return colors(d.rank); });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d4typ567/1/

Solution 2: It's also the case that d3 maintains a parent index variable for nested selections (usually denoted `ii`) that can be passed into most d3 .attr and .style functions, so you could do `.attr("cy", function(d,i, ii) { return (height/tradeByCountry.length)*ii; })` instead, but offsetting the g element is only 1 operation whereas this is done for every circle. Remember to do the same for the color (fill) function.

Comment: Thank you! I understand how d3.nest() works a lot more now!